# Loading a UITableView From A Nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, crash

I keep getting a crash when loading a UITableView. I am trying to use a cell defined in a nib file.

I have an IBOutlet defined in the view controller header file:

```
UITableViewCell *jobCell;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *jobCell;
```

This is synthesised in the implementation file.

I have a UITableViewCell created in IB and set it's identifier to JobCell.

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"JobCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JobsRootViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = jobCell;
    self.jobCell = nil;
}

// Get this job
Job *job = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Job title
UILabel *jobTitle;
jobTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tagJobTitle];
jobTitle.text = job.title;

// Job due date
UILabel *dueDate;
dueDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tagJobDueDate];
dueDate.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:job.dueDate];

// Notes icon
UIImageView *notesImageView;
notesImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:tagNotesImageView];
if ([job.notes length] > 0) {
    // This job has a note attached to it - show the notes icon
    notesImageView.hidden = NO;
}
else {
    // Hide the notes icon
    notesImageView.hidden = YES;
}

// Job completed button

// Return the cell
return cell;
```

}

When I run the app - I get a hard crash and the console reports the following:

> objc[1291]: FREED(id): message style sent to freed object=0x4046400

I have hooked up all the outlets in IB correctly. What is the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: There's a great little checkbox in xcode that you can make called NSZombiesEnabled. That will keep track of freed objects and tell you what they are. Enable it and rerun your code to figure out what message is being sent to whatever object. That might help figure out what's going on. Check out the documentation at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html and go down to the section labeled "Finding Memory Leaks" — that will show you how to do it.

Comment: I'm very new to the Xcode IDE. I can't figure out how to enable this setting...

Comment: "To activate the NSZombieEnabled facility in your application:

Choose Project > Edit Active Executable to open the executable Info window.
Click Arguments.
Click the add (+) button in the “Variables to be set in the environment” section.
Enter NSZombieEnabled in the Name column and YES in the Value column.
Make sure that the checkmark for the NSZombieEnabled entry is selected."

Which part are you getting stuck on?

EDIT: This will help you figure out precisely what's going on. You're releasing something somewhere that shouldn't be released, which is causing your crash.

Comment: Thanks saramah for your help so far. I'm getting the following error with Zombies enabled: *** -[UITableView style]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4038600. I'm not sure why [UITableView style] is being called. I push the UITableViewController onto the navigation stack like this: JobsRootViewController *jobsRootViewController = [[JobsRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JobsRootViewController" bundle:nil]; and I never set the TableViewStyle??

Comment: I suspect IB sets up the call to style for you when it's setting up the UITableView. Do you have any UITableView instances in your code? Do you release them anywhere? If not, check your connections in the xib. If you still can't figure that out, I suggest scrapping the xib and creating a new one, following instructions in http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html — try to control precisely what's going on and check for correctness at each step.

Comment: Thanks saramah - I will recreate the xib file after work this evening. The UITableViewController is pushed onto the navigation stack with [[alloc] initWithNibName] by another view controller. If I comment out the [[NSBundle] mainBundle] line AND there is only one row to display then it works OK. As soon as I need a second row the app crashes with a UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: error in the console

Comment: Keep reading the table view guide; you need to return a new UITableViewCell for each row of your table (if it's not floating around in the queue as already created) in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Unfortunately, you only ever make one in self.jobCell, and then you blow it away and use it for your first cell (which is why the case of a one-celled table works fine). In the "if cell == nil" block, you should be creating a new table cell instead of loading one from the nib, I think. If indeed JobsRootViewController is a uitableviewcell. Which it doesn't look like it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to break it up into two separate nib files and load the cell from the cell's own nib. Something to note is that you cannot set outlets like this, if you want to do that, you will need a custom UITableViewCell subclass. But if you are not wiring up anything in the cell, you can simply do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JobsRootViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this block:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JobsRootViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = jobCell; <- THIS IS A SHALLOW COPY
    self.jobCell = nil; <- YOU JUST RELEASED IT
}

// Get this job
Job *job = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Job title
UILabel *jobTitle;
jobTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:tagJobTitle]; <- CELL ISNT THERE ANYMORE
```

You're creating jobCell as an assigned property. The synthesized setter that you use when you say self.jobCell = nil releases the object that you just made cell reference. Make a deep copy instead, or don't set jobCell to nil.

Comment: Commenting out:

self.jobCell = nil;

Makes no difference - I still get the same crash and error.

Comment: Hm, the problem must be elsewhere in your code then. Try figuring out what you're sending a message to with NSZombieEnabled. Then figure out where in your code you're sending that particular message. Then figure out where you're accidentally releasing the object that you're sending a message to.

Comment: self.jobCell = nil; doesn't release the cell. It simply makes the jobCell pointer point to nil and creates a memory leak if that was the last pointer to that cell. `[self.jobCell release]` will release it.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

- **Cell**

You should register your xib file in order to use it in tableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellXibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellReuseIdentifier")
    }
```

UITebleViewDataSource method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellClass
    return cell
}
```

**TableView**

```
if let tableView: CustomTableView = nib?.first as? CustomTableView 
{
   self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```